# How accurate was Azgaar.io about what Biomes my Fantasy Map should have (realistically)?

Tags: climate, worldbuilding-process

I'm making a map for the next D&D game I will run, and I would like some second opinions on what Biomes would encompass it (Assume realistic biomes for now; no Mushroom forests or the like). Attached are a Heightmap, a map of what Azgaar thinks the Biomes would be, and an image containing some pertinent information. If these three pictures and the below information aren't enough to give sound advice, I apologize, and will try to give what info I can. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Additional Information

-This is not the only continent in its world. At least 2 more exist off-map between the two tropics (Haven't decided on a number)

-Biome colors are the default Azgaar colors (Brown is Tundra, Dark Green is Taiga, White is Glacier, Light Brown is Cold Desert, Beige is Grassland, The Lightest Green on the Main Continent is Deciduous Forrest, the next Darkest one is Temperate Rainforest, the next Darkest is Wetlands. On the large islands, the Tan is Savanah, the Lightest Green is Tropical Seasonal Forrest, the next Darkest is Tropical Rainforest, the next Darkest is Wetlands again)

-Altitude is measured in ft, and the Altitude exponent is 2.0625 (The Exponent is the value for Altitude change sharpness, according to Azgaar). Altitude is 250 ft and below for the Darkest Green, lighter shades are higher. We get to 1 mile above sea level with the Lightest shade of Yellow, We get to 2 miles above sea level with the 2nd Lightest shade of Orange, and Red is 20,000 ft above sea level and up

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: ? They are *hints*; they are reasonable hints, and quite practicable, but they remain just hints. You may use them if you want, you may disregard them if you want. The Javascript code loaded into your browser is not the author; *you* are the author. If you go to the Tools tab, you will find a Configure Biomes button, which opens a tool that allows you to reassign biomes manually.

Comment: Oh, I know that, but my question is, what do *you* think the Biomes would be. I'm asking *because* I'm going to reassign Biomes, I just want some kind strangers on the internet to lend me their expertise, tell me a thing or two about Climatology and how it would apply to this landmass. That way, it can be at least believable.

Comment: What biomes do you want? Then we can help you get there. We can't tell you what to want.

Comment: This map has most of what I want, which was what I was aiming for when creating it in Azgaar. As for a description, I want it to be Europe-like climatically, with a warmer Mediterranean at the south of the continent, and Siberian-like cold Taiga in the North. I already designed one of the other two off-map continents, and it will cover everything else I want that's not on this one (its the tropical exotic continent, with a large desert, extensive wetlands, and a sizable rainforest). Other than that, I just want advice on how contiguous the biomes should be.

Comment: I realize now that the title of my question implied... something different than what I really meant. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want.  But the map is nice.  My ideas.

[image]

1. No glaciers on the middle continent.  It is warm there.

2:  Swampy mangrove and cypress on the top of middle continent.  This is D&D: it is bullywug land.

3. Giant dry lakebed in middle continent.  There are ruins on the old shoreline from when sealevel was higher and it was connected to the ocean.
4. City to command straits.
5. More glaciers up north.  That is Sasquatch territory.

Comment: Thank you. This is the type of advice I was looking for.

Comment: Remember that there are glaciers on Kilimanjaro and the [Rwenzori mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rwenzori_Mountains) are permanently snowcapped... both places are close to the equator in what is generally considered to be quite a warm continent. [Cotopaxi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotopaxi) and other Ecuadorian volcanoes get plenty of snow, too. The warmth of the large continent is very much secondary to the height of its mountains.

Answer (score 1):

I made some tests with this program and it seems to me that it is awesome giving good results very easily and building entire world with a few clicks. Its climate simulation though lack some major influences. For example the atmospheric cells are only slightly represented by dominant winds. Tropical high and polar low pressure zones are not simulated and as result, for example, it do not create desert areas around tropics. There seems to be no ocean currents or monsoons either.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I did wonder why is was so hard to create a large & contiguous desert with Azgaar. Now I know.